# Bing Map optimzed route

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I've been investigating a little bit about the Bing Map due I need optimize some routes. Each route has 10 stops. I would like reorder the waypoints according to suggest of bing map

my code is in javascript

```
directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsItinerary') });

var startWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
     location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(XX, YY),                
});

directionsManager.addWaypoint(startWaypoint);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var waypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(XX, YY),
    })

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint);
}

var endWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
     location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(XX, YY),                
});

directionsManager.addWaypoint(endWaypoint);

directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
            routeDraggable: false,
            routeOptimization: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteOptimization.shortestDistance,
            routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving
        });

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});

directionsManager.calculateDirections();
```

On the event directionsUpdated, when the api is called, the waypoints are not reordered. Always is the same order that I send

Does the Bing Map Routes API works to reorder the waypoints when the "optimized" parameter is sent? Or it works only to minimize the distnace between 2 points?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps does not provide travelling salesmen type route optimization. The optimization mentioned in Bing Maps is in regards to how the route is calculated through the waypoints, in the order they are provided. For example, shortest distance, shortest time, shortest time with traffic.
It is possible to generate a distance matrix using the routing service and then implement a TSP algorithm through code. Here is a code sample that does this using JavaScript: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNo5cpCk-qqNaQnxWT5w